# How to obtain a list of elements contained in multiple list using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, list

Say I have codes:

```
  class Program
  {
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
      Company companyA = new Company();
      Company companyB = new Company();
      companyA.Employees = new List<string> { "A1", "A2" };
      companyB.Employees = new List<string> { "B1", "B2" };

      List<Company> companyList = new List<Company> {companyA, companyB};
      List<string> allEmployees = new List<string>();
      foreach( Company company in companyList )
      {
        allEmployees.AddRange( company.Employees );
      }

      // ...
    }

    class Company
    {
      public List<string> Employees { get; set; }
    }
  }
```

I want to fill **allEmployees** with the employees from all companies in **companyList**.

Instead of using the above codes, is it possible to get the same result by using a single LINQ statement on **companyList** object? May be something like:

```
List<string> allEmployees  = companyList.Select( ...? )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `SelectMany`

```
List<string> allEmployees = companyList.SelectMany(x => x.Employees).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `AddRange` + `SelectMany`:

```
allEmployees.AddRange( companyList.SelectMany(c => c.Employees) );
```

If you don't want to add them to an already existing list but to create a new one:

```
List<string> allEmployees = companyList.SelectMany(c => c.Employees).ToList();
```